# Inequality involving relative error and ulp

Tags: floating-point

The below quote comes from page 8 of [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://galileo.phys.virginia.edu/classes/551.jvn.fall01/goldberg.pdf). Can someone explain how the last equation involving 1/2 ulp in an inequality comes about?

> To compute the relative error that corresponds to 1/2 ulp, observe that when a real number  is approximated by the closest possible floating-point number
>
> [image]
>
> the absolute error can be as large as
>
> [image]
>
> where β′ is the digit β/2. This error is [image]
>
> Since numbers of the form [image] all have this same absolute error but have values that range between β^e and β x β^e, the relative error ranges between
>
> [image] and [image]. That is
>
> [image]

Comment: it is explained in the line(s) prior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line attempts to say that the relative error that a half an ULP corresponds to is between the two bounds shown, which were calculated in previous lines. However, instead of saying the *relative error* corresponding to half an ULP is between those bounds, it says *half an ULP* is between those bounds. That is a mistake, unless we are loose about what “ULP” means. Instead of “1/2 ULP” in that line, I would write “1/2 ULP / x”, where x is the number being considered.

(Actually, when I write about ULPs, I often write ULP(x) to indicate that the ULP is an ULP of a particular value, since the value of the unit of last place varies depending on the number.)

Comment: Of course when x is a power of two ULP(x) is still ambiguous.

Comment: @RickRegan: ULP is clearly defined as the unit in the last place. It is not defined as the distance to another representable value. There is no ambiguity in its definition.

Comment: So what is ULP(2^53)? Is it 1 or 2?

Comment: @RickRegan: It is two. Since the IEEE-754 64-bit binary floating-point  has 53-bit significands (52 directly encoded, one complicated), the last bit is 52 bits “below” the first bit. For 2**53, the highest bit has value 2**53. So the last bit has value 2**(53-52) = 2**1 = 2.

Comment: One time there could be some uncertainty about ULP(*x*) is if *x* is not a representable value. E.g., we are doing a proof, and the mathematical result in some step is *x*, and *x* is very near some power of two, but less than it. When we discuss the ULP of this value, do we mean the ULP for the “binade” it is in mathematically (the one below the power of two in question) or the ULP of the value it would be rounded to when rounding to the floating-point format? However, that is a matter for the author of the proof to settle and make clear. For representable values, there is no question.

Comment: I'm OK with your definition. But I think different people define it in different ways. Kahan (http://www.eecs.berkeley.edu/~wkahan/LOG10HAF.TXT) defines ulp(x) as "the gap between the two floating-point numbers nearest x". Wikipedia (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_in_the_last_place) says "...is the spacing between floating-point numbers, i.e., the value the least significant digit represents if it is 1". (That is contradictory -- it uses your definition and the "gap" definition).

Comment: BTW, I come at ULPs from the decimal to floating-point conversion point of view (what I think fits your "uncertainty" case): given a decimal number and a double that is a power of two, how do you check that the double is the nearest match? You need to consider the ULP (your definition) at the power of two and the ULP of the double just below.